# How to convert string with German characters to Blob in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to convert a string into a blob with the `f_strblob(CSTRING)` function of FreeAdhocUDF. At this point I do not find a way to get my special characters like ß or ä shown in the blob.

The result of f_strblob('Gemäß') is Gem..

I tried to change the character set to UTF8 of my variables, but that does not help.
Is there a masking option which I did not find?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You don't need that function. Why can't you just use `cast('your string' as blob sub_type text)? Or just assign the string to the blob (Firebird will do the conversion for you)? What Firebird version are you using? Please provide relevant DDL and explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that function, and the FreeAdhocUDF documentation also marks it as obsolete for that reason.

In a lot of situations, Firebird will automatically convert string literals to blobs (eg in statements where a string literal is assigned to a blob value), and otherwise you can explicitly cast using `cast('your string' as blob sub_type text)`.

Comment: My special characters are correct now, but I try to convert into a blob with this format: 

`{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg0\uc1\deff0\deflang0\deflangfe0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Arial;}}{\colortbl;}{\stylesheet}


\pard\fi0\li0\ql\ri0\sb0\sa0\itap0 \plain \f0\fs16 Gem\u228 \'e4\u223 \'df\par}`

but my entry is just "Gemäß"

If I insert an entry from my ERP Tool this happens automatically.

Comment: @ebug38 That changes the scope of your question drastically. That is [Rich Text Format (RTF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), and Firebird doesn't have anything to produce RTF. If you want to generate RTF, then I strongly suggest you do this in your client application.

Comment: Okay thanks. Fortunately it did not make any differences in my outputs. Thank you again!

Comment: I also suggest to avoid RTF everywhere where HTML would suffice. RTF is very sub-standard thing with many programs (including ones by Microsoft) interpreting same documents in very different ways.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use it, because my client has this kind of textfield integrated and it is implicated in many more masks.
@MarkRotteveel
Is there a possibility to concat the richtext (which is always the same) with my custom text (which is somewhere in the mid of that richtext) ? So I could convert my custom string (e.g '\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg0\uc1\deff0\deflang0\') to blob and this is saved in the db? I do not want to convert a text into rtf, just a string (which contains the rtf already) into a blob.

Comment: @ebug38 Maybe, but not easily: RTF requires non-ASCII to be encoded in a special way (as already shown by your first comment). And although you'll be able to store it in Firebird no problem, generating correct RTF inside Firebird SQL language will be pretty hard to do (in that example you quote `Gemäß` to `Gem\u228 \'e4\u223 \'df` already requires a dual encoding (both `\u228` and \'e4` encode `ä`, while `\u223` and `\'df` both encode `ß`)